# Objective-C: поиск по изображениям в таблице

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Я хочу выполнить поиск изображений с помощью search bar в tableview. Мой поиск работает, но для показа изображения я использую этот код в

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

_array18 = [[NSArray alloc ]initWithObjects:@"title1",@"title2",@"title3", nil];
_image = [[NSArray alloc ]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title1.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"title2.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"title3.jpg"], nil];

}

- (void)searchForText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{

NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

_searchResults = [_array18 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Но код в `cellForRowAtIndexPath` не является простым решением, если у меня есть 100 изображений или больше мне нужно создавать 100 проверок. Как можно упростить этот код или есть ли более простое решение?

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell= [[cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

if ([[_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"title1"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [_image objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    if ([[_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"title2"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [_image objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    if ([[_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"title3"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [_image objectAtIndex:2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем 100 проверок писать, если можно сразу подставлять в картинку: [UIImage imageNamed[_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте словарь:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSMutableDictionary *dic;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _array18 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"title1",@"title2",@"title3", nil];
    [self initDic];
}

- (void)initDic {
    self.dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:@{ @"title1":[UIImage imageNamed:@"title1.jpg"],
                                                                  @"title2":[UIImage imageNamed:@"title2.jpg"],
                                                                  @"title3":[UIImage imageNamed:@"title3.jpg"]
                                                                  }];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.imageView.image = [dic objectForKey:[_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Форматирование кода оставляет желать лучшего.

Comment: Поправил. Так лучше?

Comment: Да, так понятней.